# File Upload Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-web-components

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="accordion">
        <lightning-accordion active-section-name="DocumentsFromSeller">
            <lightning-accordion-section name="DocumentsFromSeller" label="Documents From Seller">
                <template for:each={certificates} for:item="certificate">
                    <lightning-card key={certificate.name} >
                        <div class="file-upload">
                            <label >
                                {certificate.uploadLabel}
                            </label>
                            <input type="file" id={certificate.name} accept={acceptedFormats} onchange={handleFileChange} data-certificate-name={certificate.name} />
                        </div>
                    </lightning-card>
                </template>
            </lightning-accordion-section>
        </lightning-accordion>
```

**JS:**

```js
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

export default class FileUploadFromSellerComponent extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;

    certificates = [
 ];

    get acceptedFormats() {
        return ['.pdf', '.docx'];
    }

    handleFileChange(event) {
        const fileInput = event.target;
        const files = fileInput.files;
        const maxFileSize = 2 * 1024 * 1024; // 2 MB in bytes

        const certificateName = fileInput.dataset.certificateName;
        const certificate =
            this.certificates.find((cert) => cert.name === certificateName) ||
            this.certificates2.find((cert) => cert.name === certificateName);

        for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            const file = files[i];
            const fileSize = file.size || (file.documentId && file.documentId.size);

            if (certificate && fileSize) {
                certificate.uploadedFiles = certificate.uploadedFiles || [];

                if (fileSize <= maxFileSize) {
                    certificate.uploadedFiles.push(file);
                    this.dispatchEvent(
                        new ShowToastEvent({
                            title: 'Success',
                            message: 'File "' + file.name + '" uploaded successfully.',
                            variant: 'success',
                        })
                    );
                } else {
                    // Clear the invalid file from the input
                    fileInput.value = '';
                    this.dispatchEvent(
                        new ShowToastEvent({
                            title: 'Error',
                            message: 'File "' + file.name + '" exceeds the 2MB limit and was not uploaded.',
                            variant: 'error',
                        })
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hi all,
I have made a custom component to upload file. Here my query is if I upload a file it gonna save in "FILES". I have many Leads and this component is added for record page if I attach a file it uploads in file content, can we make a field which holds the attached pdf/doc link to open is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.You can create a custom field and have the link stored.

First you will have to understand how ContentDistribution works.Click [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentdistribution.htm) for the documentation
Steps:

1. Create your contentversion for you file.
2. create your content documentlink.
3. create the contentdistribution
4. take the DistributionPublicUrl of the contentdistribution store it in the custom field.